# how to fix to Joomla 1.5 URL Redirecting Vulnerability?

Tags: security, joomla, xss

I have today discovred a problem on my website

This vulnerability sends my visitor to a custom url "ya.ru"

Here you can see what is the **vulnerability**

**http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/14722**

help to find a way to fix please 
thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a fairly old exploit - the best way to keep any Joomla installation secure is to keep the software up to date.

The last version of Joomla! 1.5 was 1.5.26, it's no longer available on the main download page as it's not supported anymore. However, it is still available via "[Update Manager](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/installers/9332)" or this page http://www.joomla.org/component/content/article/185-uncategorised/5465-download.html

Updating to the last version of Joomla! 1.5 will fix this vulnerability.

Comment: indeed it is an old version but the best one